# Automatic generation of rest api in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, automation, code-generation

Are there any tools to automate generation of php code implementing rest API? Preferably in phalcon. I can generate whole MVC structure of new project including models based on existing database. What I'd like to get is restfull api generated so I could focus only on implementing buisness-specific functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about something that will generate in Phalcon but [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) by Zend is pretty good at taking care of all of the REST CRUD and leaving you to just tie it to your models/database.

It has a great interface and some powerful features (like helping deal with authentication, versioning etc).

[Here](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/12/03/create-a-restful-api-with-apigility/) is a slightly out of date tutorial but it might give you a bit of an idea of what is possible.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning api generator for Laravel https://github.com/SoliDry/api-generator with complete support of json-api spec + OpenApi/Swagger configuration based on yaml/json.

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/automatic-php-rest-api-generator-from-mysql-database/25152744 please check this. Simple tool I found over internet.